# JS: DP rod cutting . A recurrence doesn't go further than i = 1 in "for cycle"

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I have met some difficulties with the understanding how works cycle "for" and recurrence together. I tried to implement the rod cutting problem in JavaScript. (the original code was written in Java).

**Problem:**
The problem is that the recurrence goes down in each cycle i = 1 to bottom  until it reaches the lowest value but then it doesn't execute next cycle i=2. What is wrong in this code?

**Code:**

```
var p = [2,5,8,9,10,17,17,20,24,30];
function cut_rod(p,n){
        console.log("           level=",n); 
        if(n == 0){
            return 0;
        } 
        q = Number.MIN_VALUE;

        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            console.log("           i=",i);
            q = Math.max(q, p[i-1] + cut_rod(p, n-i));
            console.log("           q=",q);         
        }         
        return q;
}
console.log(cut_rod(p,10));
```

The same problem was met when I decided to implement the recurrence which just execute each step of each cycle. (just for the understanding of recurrence without solving some problem).

**code:**

```
function test(sum){
    console.log("i'm here sum",sum);
    if (sum < 1) {
        console.log("       ",sum," is less then 1, return",1);
        return x=1;
    }
    else{
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
            console.log("           i=",i);
            x = test(sum-i)+1;
            console.log("           x=",x)
        }       
    }
    return x;
} 

console.log("----------------->start"); 
console.log("answer",test(5));
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scope issue. Your `i` and `q` variables are **global** variables, not **local** variables.

Change `for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){ ...` to `for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++){ ...`

and `q = Number.MIN_VALUE;` to  `var q = Number.MIN_VALUE;`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code:

```
cutRod = function(p, n) {
    if (n === 0)
        return 0;
    var q = -Infinity;
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
        q = Math.max(q, p[i] + cutRod(p, n - i - 1));
    return q;
};

arr = [1, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 18, 22, 25, 30];
debug("Maximum obtainable value is " + cutRod(arr, 5));
```

Look at line 5 the for loop condition is `i < n`.
And at line 6 the 2nd argument to the recursive call of cutRod is `n - i - 1`.
Try do this adjusts in your code and see if it works.